# How to update nested JSON data type in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

Using JSON_SET I have no problem updating simple JSON datatype, but with nested it just doesn't work.

How query supposed to look like with format like this:

```
{  
   "textures":[  
      {  
         "label":"test",
         "types":{  
            "t_1":0,
            "t_2":0
         }
      },
      {  
         "label":"KEK",
         "types":{  
            "t_1":0,
            "t_2":0
         }
      }
   ],
   "weapons":[  
      {  
         "name":"WW_SHT",
         "ammo":0
      },
      {  
         "name":"WW_DSS",
         "ammo":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Some rows might be empty, some rows won't have "weapons" structure.

What I tried:

```
UPDATE `player`   SET `info` = COALESCE(
    JSON_MERGE(
      `info`,
      JSON_OBJECT('textures',
        JSON_OBJECT('types',
          JSON_OBJECT('t_1', '1', 't_2', '0')
        )
      )
    ),
    JSON_INSERT(
      JSON_OBJECT(),
      '$.textures',
       JSON_OBJECT('types',
         JSON_OBJECT('t_1', '1', 't_2', '0')
       )
    )
  );
```

I want to update t_1 to change value from 0 to 1

Answer (score 2):

You are really convoluding your code.  Try your update with json_set or json_replace and something like

```
... WHERE doc->"$.textures[*].types.t_1" = 0
```

Your code is a little hard to read and comprehend with some many functions embedded together

BTW json_merge is deprecated in MySQL 8

And you will want  to read https://elephantdolphin.blogspot.com/2018/09/json-paths-and-mysql-json-functions.html

Comment: doesn't work if there is empty field or no textures field

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [JSON_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace)

```
UPDATE player SET info = JSON_REPLACE(info, '$.textures[0].t_1', '1');
```

However, this only replaces the value in the 0th texture. If you have multiple textures, you can find out how many textures:

```
SELECT JSON_LENGTH(info, '$.textures') AS textures_count FROM player;
```

P.S.: This is probably an app that would be better off using a traditional
normalized database. Actually, I haven't seen any example of JSON in MySQL that wouldn't be easier if the tables were designed in a traditional way.

Comment: doesn't work if there is empty field or no textures field

Comment: You didn't specify in your question above which fields were subject to be missing.